# Exporting KendoUI widget spreadsheet to .xlsx

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm evaluating Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC for my software developer company, very very good widgets indeed; specially the spreadsheet.
But trying the export feature in the spreadsheet I'm facing a problem with a formula in a cell (I guess, for scape double quotes in json to bind the spreadsheet), and the scenario looks as follow:

For test and validation purposes the spreadsheet is binding from a json file (just like the demo here http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/spreadsheet/server-side-import-export) , and in a cell I'm evaluating a formula (AVERAGEIF) behavior and works like a charm, the formula in json is:

```
{ "value": "", "formula":"AVERAGEIF(C2:C5,\"<>39\")", "format": "", "background": "#f2f2f2", "color": "#00b050", "bold": true, "textAlign": "center", "index": 3 }
```

As the demo, the export method that I'm using is (asp net mvc5 C#):

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Download(string data, string extension)
    {
        var workbook = Workbook.FromJson(data);
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Save(stream, extension);

            var mimeType = Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.MimeTypes.ByExtension[extension];
            return File(stream.ToArray(), mimeType, "Exported" + extension);
        }
    }
```

After the execution, I'm getting this error:

[image: vs exception]

And this is the stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current
>   state of the object.]
>   Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.CellValueFactory.CreateFormulaCellValue(String
>   value, Worksheet worksheet, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex) +123
>   Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.CellValueFactory.ToFormulaCellValue(String
>   value, Worksheet worksheet, Int32 rowIndex, Int32 columnIndex) +48
>   Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.Model.CellSelection.SetValueAsFormula(String
>   value) +149    Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook.SetCells(Row srcRow,
>   Worksheet documentSheet) +558
>   Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook.ToDocument() +846
>   Telerik.Web.Spreadsheet.Workbook.Save(Stream output, String extension)
>   +39    Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Controllers.SpreadsheetController.Download(String
>   data, String extension) in
>   C:\Spreadsheet\Server_Side_Import_ExportController.cs:35
>   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +245
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +435
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod()
>   +76    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +73
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +117    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +323    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +47
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +185
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +42
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +62
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +70
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +56
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +37
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9721605    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

When I try to export the spreadsheet with "normal" formulas (those that not need escape double quotes) the export behavior works as expected.

Thanks so much in advance for your help !